# UIKit.UIBarButtonItem fails build with Xamarin.Forms 4.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, collectionview

I updated my xamarin forms to latest xamarin form 4.0. Now after updating it I am getting following error:

Can't resolve the reference 'UIKit.UIBarButtonItem Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ToolbarItemExtensions::ToUIBarButtonItem(Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItem,System.Boolean)', referenced from the method 'UIKit.UIBarButtonItem Naxam.Controls.Platform.iOS.TopTabbedRenderer/<>c::b__57_0(Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItem)' in 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Naxam needs to update their controls to support Xamarin.Forms 4.0 Preview, you can either mod' their open source controls to support it, or go back to a stable version of Forms 3.x which is supported.

Comment: I need to use the latest feature CollectionView that comes with xamarin.forms 4.0.  That's why I need to update xamarin forms to 4.0

Comment: Then either update the source of Naxam or choose a different implementation.

Comment: You can add a new issue here https://github.com/NAXAM/toptabbedpage-xamarin-forms/issues